# JS code not recognized in modal body..why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I used a template with modals..there's a main modal code used for all the modal pop-ups...each modal is inside an `<a></a>` tag. I added the html inside each modal specific to the exercise and linked my javascript file to display a quick example of each exercise, but the code is not being recognized when I try to demonstrate the exercise. I changed the `<a>` to `<div>` but that didn't help. The JS exercises have worked before in another project in modals I built but not here and all code worked previously.

Here's the html for the exercise

```
<p style="text-align: center;">Enter a number between 1 - 100.
    <input class="inputBox" type="text" id="fizzBuzzText" name="number" placeholder="Type Number Here">
    <button class="fizzBuzzBtn">Try it!</button>
    <div class="resetButton">
        <button type="reset" class="clearList">Reset</button>
    </div>
    <p class="fizzbuzz"></p>

</div>
```

Here's the javascript thats linked

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('.fizzBuzzBtn').click(function () {
        var newNumber = $('.inputBox').val()
        console.log(newNumber);

        var num = +newNumber
        $('.inputBox').val('');
        $('.fizzbuzz').empty();

        if (num !== NaN && num >= 1 && num <= 100 && num % 1 == 0) {

            var i = 1
            while (i <= num) {
                if ((i % 3 === 0) && (i % 5 === 0)) {
                    $('.fizzbuzz').append('FizzBuzz' + " ");
                } else if (i % 3 == 0) {
                    $('.fizzbuzz').append('Fizz' + " ");
                } else if (i % 5 == 0) {
                    $('.fizzbuzz').append('Buzz' + " ");
                } else {
                    $('.fizzbuzz').append(i + " ");
                }
                i++;
            }
        } else {
            alert("Please type in a whole number between 1 and 100!");
        }
    });

    $('.resetButton').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#fizzBuzzText').empty();
        $('.fizzbuzz').empty();
    });
});
```

I don't get any errors, it just doesn't work inside the modal body. Is this a common error for template modals?

Comment: Your script like you post it hre work. And I not see here `modal`. What modal? You show result in new modal div created with js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work in a modal from, because you add the htm to document before it loaded, but your js function loaded one when document completed `$(document).ready(function (){` and have efect only on the html elements witch is on the document in that moment, not on element witch will be created before.

To work you need to recal function from `$(document).ready(function (){`

for example

```
   $(document).ready(function (){ somefunctionname(); });

   function somefunctionname(){
    $('.fizzBuzzBtn').click(function () {
   /* put your code here*/
  });
   }
```

add to js code that creadte modal form the `somefunctionname();` after it will work

Comment: Thanks so much for a response..so I added the code to the modal like a class or id? I added the example and put my code after the click function

Comment: I don't understand you. If I undestand you you create with js new html elements.Your function work only for element that is on document when it loaded complet and function `$(document).ready(function ` run and add to all existind on document elements with class `fizzBuzzBtn` a event onclick `$('.fizzBuzzBtn').click(function` . If you after add new elements on form with class `fizzBuzzBtn` and click on it you dont't see changes, because you need to recal your function that is in `$(document).ready`.

Comment: I say you to make your function `function somefunctionname()` and call id on document ready like `$(document).ready(function (){ somefunctionname(); });`. And when you create new elements with class `fizzBuzzBtn` with `JS` you also after create it recall fucntion  `somefunctionname();` to atach onclick event to new created elements.

Comment: Thanks so much, I finally got it to work with your explanation

Answer (score 0):

```
     .append( "<p>Test</p>" );
```

not

```
    .append( "Test" );
```

try

```
    .html('test');
```

> http://api.jquery.com/append/
>
> http://api.jquery.com/html/

Also may be your's `if` conditions not satisfacted

Comment: I tried what you posted but I added an alert to the 'try it' button and i don't even get an alert, just not working...